# Is that a bug, when I send zero to to funtion luaO_ceillog2?

Tags: lua

I'a reading lua source code which version is 5.3. And i found the function 
int luaO_ceillog2 (unsigned int x) in lobject.c file doest't take a special discuss for 0. When 0 was send to this fuction, it would return 32. Does this is a bug? I was confused.

Comment: This function is not exposed to user.  It is only used internally [here](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html#setnodevector) and [here](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html#countint).  Obviously, `luaO_ceillog2` is guaranteed to be not invoked with zero argument.  So, it is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

`luaO_ceillog2` is a function that's only used internally. Its name infers that it calculates `ceil` (maximum number that's not less than) of `log2` of the argument.

Mathematically,  log<sub>b</sub>x is only valid for `x` who is positive. So `0` is not a valid argument for this function, I don't think this counts as a bug.